# Which architecture in aws should I choose for higher availability? EBS+ multi-attach or RDS+ read replica?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-ebs

I'm just new learner on AWS, and when I see the latest post of multi-attach, I was confused about which way should I use, can someone advise a scenario on either way is better? (Main concern for me is availability considering both architectures are talking about high availability and helping concurrent writes)

Comment: I realized that there are types of RDS and EBS, when I looked at the maximum iops, EBS actually had a larger IOPS with provisioned storage. So in this case I should use EBS?